# Binding javascript to new rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple table which has a some information displayed. To view the details of that row i have a javascript function:

```
$('#production tr').bind("click", function(){
    reviewProductionOrder(this);
});
```

This lets me select the row and display information appropriately. However i have a date picker on top which filters the results accordingly

```
$('#view').bind("click", function(){
    var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
    var to_date = $('#to_date').val();

    $.ajax({
         type : "post", url : "data.php", data : "from_date=" + from_date + "&to_date=" + to_date,
         success : function(data) {
         if(data != '')
             $('#production tbody').html(data);
         }
    });
});
```

The function above lets me add the data to the table. Now i thought that `bind` would let me bind the javascript function to the newly generated rows. However when i click on those rows, i am unable to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#production').on('click' , 'tr', function() {
    // your processing here
});
```

the `$(document)` part must be a parent element the element you want to listen on the event for, from the `on()` doc page :

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.

Comment: I have tried using on instead on bind in the above code. All i did was replaced `bind` with `on`, is that alright?

Comment: @Namit nope - read the help and my answer - you need to use `on` on a parent

Comment: A better use would be to place the delegate on the `'#production'` element instead of on the `document`. There's no need to run the selector against all clicks on the page if we're only interested in clicks within the `'#production'` element.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways for you to do that.  First of all, you need to know that you can only bind events on existing DOM objects. So when you .bind at first, you bind on the existing element, not the new ones you want to create.  In order to bypass that, jQuery has the fonction ".live" which work exactly as .bind, but keep applying it on DOM object after the initial calls.  The main problem with that function is that it is slower.  The difference is big if you have a lot of dynamic javascript and animations but changes nothing is there's only that 1 table on the page.  You could also rebind the event on the new appended object saying your response from the ajax call is pure html you could, for example, do that:

```
 $('#production tbody').html(data).find('#production tr').bind("click", function(){
    reviewProductionOrder(this); })
```

That way, you get to bind the event AFTER it was appended.

Hope it helped.